# Javascript dropdown code doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I have a very basic website with a textfield and a dropdown. If I click on an element from the dropdown, the text area gets updated with some text.

Here's the code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'macros.html' as macros %}


{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-md-6">
        {% call macros.render_ajax_form(form, 'input-form', 'translate()') %}
            {{ macros.render_field(form.style, type='select') }}
            {{ macros.render_field(form.input_text, placeholder='Enter Text', type='textarea', rows=18, cols=50) }}
        {% endcall %}
    </div>
    <div class="well col-md-6">
        <div class="output-header"> 
            <label>Output</label>
        </div>
        <p id="loading">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
                    <span>Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p id="output"></p>
        <p id="status"></p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the JS:

```
// Progress Bar Constants
var WORDS_PER_MILLISEC = 0.02
var MILLISECS = 200

// Default Author Text
var HEMINGWAY = "Hi, ";

var DICKENS = "Hi, ";

var SHAKESPEARE = "Hi Best regards,";

var RAPPERS = "Hello S, further.";

function getWidthPercentage(selector) {
return 100 * parseFloat($(selector).css('width')) / parseFloat($(selector).parent().css('width'));
}

function set_default_text(e) {
$("#input_text").val(window[e.target.value.toUpperCase()]);
}

function download() {
var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent($("#output").text()));
pom.setAttribute('download', "output.txt");
pom.click();
}

function compute_changes(converted_text) {

var original_lines = $("#input_text").val();
var converted_lines = converted_text;


// converted_words[i] = '<highlight data-toggle="tooltip" title="' + original_text + '">' + converted_text + '</highlight>';


$("#output").html(original_lines);
//$("highlight").tooltip();

}

function translate() {

compute_changes($("#input_text").val());

}

function set_progress() {
var words = $('#input_text').val().split(" ").length;

var progress = setInterval(function() {
    var $bar = $('.progress-bar');

    if (getWidthPercentage('.progress-bar')>=100) {
        clearInterval(progress);
    } else {
        $bar.width(getWidthPercentage('.progress-bar') + ((WORDS_PER_MILLISEC * MILLISECS) / words) * 100 + "%");
    }
}, MILLISECS);
}

function clearFormSubmission() {
$('#output').empty();
$('.help-block').remove();
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var $loading = $('.progress').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
    set_progress();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $('.progress-bar').width("100%");
    $loading.hide();
    $('.progress-bar').width("0%");
  });

$('#style').change(set_default_text).change();
});
```

In Opera it works but in Chrome it doesn't. I can't see any text in the text field and also can't choose any element from the list.

EDIT:

HTML with the form:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'macros.html' as macros %}


{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-md-6">
        {% call macros.render_ajax_form(form, 'input-form', 'translate()') %}
            {{ macros.render_field(form.style, type='select') }}
            {{ macros.render_field(form.input_text, placeholder='Enter Text', type='textarea', rows=18, cols=50) }}
        {% endcall %}
    </div>
    <div class="well col-md-6">
        <div class="output-header"> 
            <label>Output</label>
        </div>
        <p id="loading">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
                    <span>Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p id="output"></p>
        <p id="status"></p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Python file with the form:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError


class WordLength(object):
def __init__(self, max=-1, message=None):
    self.max = max
    if not message:
        message = u'Input cannot be more than %i words long.' % (max)
    self.message = message

def __call__(self, form, field):
    l = field.data and len(field.data.split(" ")) or 0
    if self.max != -1 and l > self.max:
        raise ValidationError(self.message)


class InputForm(Form):
input_text = TextAreaField('Input', validators=[WordLength(max=1000)])
style = SelectField('Style',
                    choices=[("dickens", "A copywriter proposal"), ("shakespeare", "A social media marketer proposal"), ("hemingway", "A developer proposal"), ("rappers", "A designer proposal")])
```

Comment: That looks like Twig. Show us the *rendered* markup.

Comment: The textarea is missing from the code you posted, the select is missing from the code you posted and the onchange of the select is missing from the code you posted.

Comment: @HMR I updated the code